# Two nearly identical pieces of code, but one produces a localunbounderror in python

Tags: python, local

So, I'm creating two random word generators, one based on bigrams and the other based on trigrams. In each case I've set up a dictionary (either called bigrams, which has two nested dictionaries or trigrams, which has three nested dictionaries)...and there is a lot of other code but here's the line that causes a problem in the trigram generator:

```
 #generates random phonemes
 def generate_trigramphoneme(phoneme1, phoneme2):
    rand = random.uniform(0,1)

    **for phoneme3 in trigrams[phoneme1][phoneme2]:**
        rand -= trigrams[phoneme1][phoneme2][phoneme3]

        if rand < 0.0: return phoneme3
    return phoneme3
```

where the variable "phoneme3" produces a local unbound error.

Here, though, in my bigram generator (which works), the variable "Following" is fine, and doesn't produce an error:

```
def generate_bigramphoneme(phoneme):
    rand = random.uniform(0,1)
    for following in bigrams[phoneme]:
        rand -= bigrams[phoneme][following]
        if rand < 0.0: return following
    return following
```

I looked up unbound local errors in python on eli bendersky's website, which helped me understand the error, but I still don't know how to get rid of it, or why the bigram code doesn't produce an error...

Comment: can you show us the structure of `phoneme1 ` and `phoneme2 `

Comment: so this is the dictionary: trigrams = defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(lambda:0.0))), and phoneme1 is just calling an element within trigrams, phoneme2 is calling on an element within that, and i'm trying to iterate over all the phoneme3s within that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you do have a `trigrams` defined somewhere, it may be that with your arguments, `trigrams[phoneme1][phoneme2]` is an empty iterable, therefore the loop never executes and `phoneme3` doesn’t get bound.

Comment: That isn't the issue; then you could never iterate over a empty list. Meaning that the `for loop` would never be executed.

Comment: hmm I didn't see the return at the bottom the error should be attributed to the 4th line. @Vasiliy you are correct! upped.

Comment: I think the critical difference between this loop and many others is the second return statement, outside the loop. You can iterate over an empty array, as long as you don't do that. You have expanded the scope where you try to reference the variable, but you haven't ensured that it is always bound before you reference it.

Comment: Hmmm...so when I put in print commands for phoneme1 and phoneme2, and just have the code return a # sign instead of phoneme3, everything prints, so I'm not sure if it's a problem with the loop or the variable phoneme3...but yes trigrams is defined elsewhere as a dictionary, with two more layers of nested dictionaries within it, which is why I'm trying to call everything in that third layer with phoneme3 in trigrams[phoneme1][phoneme2]

Comment: @user1742383 Can you show your `trigrams` and the values of `phoneme1` and `phoneme2` you call with?

Comment: trigrams = defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(lambda:0.0)))

    //#trains on training file
    //lines = fn.readlines()
    //for line in lines:
        syllables = line.split()
        syllables[0] = '#'
        syllables.append('#')

        #increases count in dictionary for every occurrance of a triplet of phonemes
        j = 0
        for i in xrange(1, len(syllables)-1):
            trigrams[syllables[j]][syllables[j+1]][syllables[j+2]] += 1
            j += 1

Comment: @CFC Okay, what I actually meant was: you should check that `trigrams[phoneme1][phoneme2]` is non-empty when you call your function. You can do so by putting `print trigrams[phoneme1][phoneme2]` at the top of the function.

Comment: @VasilyFaronov interesting... it prints like this: defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x026312F0>, {})

Comment: @CFC That’s it. Your dict is empty. You have no trigrams for that pair of phoneme 1 and 2. Therefore, Python never executes your `for` loop, and never assigns a value to `phoneme3` (there is nothing to assign). But you still ask it to `return phoneme3`.